# Mule 3.7.0 runtime error

Tags: mule

I am trying to deploy my app to mule standalone 3.7.0, but I'm getting this error:

```
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   + Failed to deploy artifact 'tt', see below                +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ClassNotFoundException: scala.Option
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:197) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:355) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.7.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_91]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_91]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/home/user/mule-standalone-3.7.0/apps/tt/pro.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
```

I understand it has to do with this: `http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]:` but I have `data-weave transformer` that I really need in my project, so my question is: Does mule standalone 3.7.0 support data weave??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataWeave is an enterprise feature so your app won't work if you're deploying to a CE instance. HTH

Comment: so what is the alternative for CE version?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Since data weave is not supported in CE edition you need to write an XSLT code,If you want an easy GUI mapping,then you can use Altov map force and copy the xslt code from output and paste it in the xslt transformer.

Answer (score 0):

As someone said before, this feature is only available in Enterprise Edition.

I haven't tried the Altov mapping (I will try it, here the link [Altova](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html)) but I think the best way is using custom transformers, such as java, groovy, etc. It also provides you the advantage to apply some logic in the transformation easily.

Answer (score 0):

the response of @afelisatti so good. But you can deploy successful with mule standalone 3.7.3: https://www.mulesoft.com/ty/dl/mule